# Red Black Tree AttributeError on NoneType

Tags: python, algorithm, red-black-tree, nonetype

My problem stems from trying to insert the last node (red one) in these two scenarios:

[image]

[image]

This is the traceback message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/chris/Documents/CS223/Assignment4/redblacktree.py", line 24, in insert
    self._insert(Node(data, None, 0))
  File "/home/chris/Documents/CS223/Assignment4/redblacktree.py", line 67, in _insert
    self._insertFix(z)
  File "/home/chris/Documents/CS223/Assignment4/redblacktree.py", line 71, in _insertFix
    while(z.parent.color is 1):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'color'
```

The algorithms I am using are from the book "Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Ed. by
Cormen".

I cannot for the life of me figure out how "z.parent" is a `NoneType` object when it in fact has its parent as the node above it.

Here is the code in question:

```
class RBTree:
    __slots__ = {'_root'}

    def __init__(self):
        self._root = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if(self._root is None):
            self._root = Node(data, None, 0)
        else:
            self._insert(Node(data, None, 0))

    def _insert(self, z):
        y = None
        x = self._root
        while(x is not None):
            y = x
            if(z.data < x.data):
                x = x.left
            else:
                x = x.right
        z.parent = y
        if(y is None):
            self._root = z
        elif(z.data < y.data):
            y.left = z
        else:
            y.right = z

        z.left = None
        z.right = None
        z.color = 1
        self._insertFix(z)

    def _insertFix(self, z):
        print("Print z from _insertFix: " + str(z.data) + "\n")
        while(z.parent.color is 1):
            if(z.parent == z.parent.parent.left):
                y = z.parent.parent.right
                if(y.color is 1):
                    z.parent.color = 0
                    y.color = 0
                    z.parent.parent.color = 1
                    z = z.parent.parent
                else:
                    if(z == z.parent.right):
                        z = z.parent
                        self._rotateLeft(z)
                    z.parent.color = 0
                    z.parent.parent = 1
                    self._rotateRight(z.parent.parent)
            else:
                y = z.parent.parent.left
                if(y.color is 1):
                    z.parent.color = 0
                    y.color = 0
                    z.parent.parent.color = 1
                    z = z.parent.parent
                else:
                    if(z == z.parent.left):
                        z = z.parent
                        self._rotateRight(z)
                    z.parent.color = 0
                    z.parent.parent = 1
                    self._rotateLeft(z.parent.parent)
        self._root.color = 0

    def _rotateLeft(self, x):
        y = x.right
        x.right = y.left
        if(y.left is not None):
            y.left.parent = x
        y.parent = x.parent
        if(x.parent is not None):
            self._root = y
        elif(x == x.parent.left):
            x.parent.left = y
        else:
            x.parent.right = y
        y.left = x
        x.parent = y

    def _rotateRight(self, x):
        x = y.left
        y.left = x.right
        if(x.right is not None):
            x.right.parent = y
        x.parent = y.parent
        if(y.parent is None):
            self._root = x
        elif(y == y.parent.right):
            y.parent.right = x
        else:
            y.parent.left = x
        x.right = y
        y.parent = x

class Node:
    __slots__ = {"_left", "_right", "_parent", "_data", "_color"}

    def __init__(self, data, parent, color):
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
        self._parent = parent
        self._data = data
        self._color = color
```

I am testing my code using the interpreter, as I don't have a `main` yet to be called. I think I just need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things that hopefully will give you a push in the right direction for your assignment...

First, I would recommend putting some driver code in the main portion of your module, so it will execute when the file is executed (as opposed to imported). This will allow you to more tightly iterate/debug/experiment, without having to retype everything into the interactive interpreter.

Something like this at the end of your file (with the `print` there mainly to serve as a good breakpoint location):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tree1 = RBTree()
    tree2 = RBTree()

    for x in (3, 5, 6, 7):
        tree1.insert(x)

    for x in (5, 3, 6, 2):
        tree2.insert(x)

    print "done"
```

It's not quite clear from those images if the order I used above is the exact order in which you're inserting them -- change the order as needed (and also include in your question for enhanced clarity).

Armed with this driver code, I would then recommend you use the debugger ([**pudb**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) is quite good, IMO -- it's the debugger I generally  use) to get a better sense of where things are going wrong. That will let you step through the code and get a sense for how the tree rebalancing is going, and why `z` might be `None` in this case.

Not sure how much experience you have using debuggers, but if you haven't had much occasion to do so, this is a great time to start -- it can often be invaluable.

One tip regarding *pudb*: You can drop down into an interactive *Python* shell by hitting `<shift> + !` (exit with `<ctrl> + d`), and in this shell it contains your current running environment, so you can print (or pretty-print) variables, run various functions, etc.

Comment: I was able to see what was the problem using the debugger. Now I'm stumped as to why its happening because the algorithm is known to work. The problem occurs at the line where it goes: `y = z.parent.parent.right`. This causes `y` to always be None in the scenario described above. Could you point out my mistake because I'm not seeing it?

Comment: I was able to figure out my problem after hours upon hours of debugging. And it was as simple as having `if(x.parent is **not** None):` checking the wrong condition in `_rotateLeft` and `_rotateRight`.. It is suppose to check if `x.parent` ****is**** in fact `None`.

Comment: Ah, cool -- glad you found it. I've certainly had situations like that in the past -- spent hours tracking down the problem and it turned out to be a one-line fix (or a one word fix).